# Is Apache Spark suitable for real-time financial computations?

Tags: apache-spark, finance

Is Apache Spark suitable for real-time financial computations, e.g. computation of time-weighted returns, risk metrics, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Being a general purpose computing engine and supporting streaming I would say yes.

However, the question for you is: do you need to process large amount of data across clusters?

If so, have a look at this post showing how to deal with financial maths in Spark: 
http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/07/estimating-financial-risk-with-apache-spark/